# using QuickContactBadge menu for something else than contacts

Tags: android, menu

Hi i am wondering how (possible?) to use the QuickContactBadge widget found when pressing on a contact in for example the phone app of android. but i dont want to use it on a contact, i want to use as an options menu with my own options inside the widget.

Answer (score 1):

@Emil: The default QuickContactBadge widget is only available for contacts in android, since api level 6. If you want the same custom quick action widget(similar to the context menu), [here](http://code.google.com/p/devoquickaction/) you go. Let me know, if this is what you want and it gets work for you or not?